# Overheating LM386

Tags: lm386, overheat

I am still trying to build a simple audio amplifier using the [LM386](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf). I also found some older LM386 in my department, since my previous batch ***may*** be corrupted.

Using [this](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/lm386-audio-amplifier-circuit) circuit I rebuilt it using a breadboard.

[image: lm386_simple]

On the Pin5_OUT are headphones and an oscilloscope. The circuit is powered with the 5V output of an Arduino Nano.

Measuring key points:

- V_pin5out = 0.825V (better than the 0V from my previous circuits, but still not 2.5V)
- V_DD = 4.71V (between the 5V pin of the arduino and GND)
- V_pin6 = 4.65V (supply pin of the chip).

There is still no audible output from the headphones and in addition the chip gets extremely hot (I pulled the plug at around 80°C).

Is there an error in my the circuit (picture above)?

Are these normal operating conditions?

Are the 2.5V bias measured only at low noises and change with the volume?

EDIT: I draw a schematic as I see the board, since the picture seems to be confusing
[image: lm386_real]

Comment: *Is there an error in the circuit?* - what circuit?

Comment: If I compare your breadboard and the linked breadboard, the latter is way more "readable". Where does the yellow wire from pin 6 go to? I *guess* to the + power line, but it is invisible in your picture. Also the connection of the 2 blue caps is not clear. Neither is the connection to the potmeter.

Comment: A pic of a messy breadboard isn't a schematic. We'd need the schematic you based the breadboard circuit on. Though overall, error and breadboard are pretty much synonymous. Soldering is always preferable.

Comment: My soldered board from yesterday showed no response from the output or on the trimpot, therefore I rebuilt it on the breadboard in order to change parts more easily

Comment: Why the capacitors on output pin 5 are the wrong way around? First of all, electrolytics do not tolerate much voltage of wrong polarity, and judging from the capacitor size, the cap with 10 ohms in series should not be an electrolytic to begin with. That size of electrolytic is not even near 47 nF.

Comment: *the chip gets extremely hot* Smells like you suffer from **oscillations**. Did you follow the **PCB layout example** as shown in the datasheet? Did you add all the components as suggested in the schematic in the datasheet? The LM386 has a sensitive input but (relatively) high current output so you have to make sure that the output current doesn't feed back into the input. If it does, you might get oscillations and those can heat up the chip. Maybe a minor issue but not all pins on the adapter board appear to be soldered properly.

Comment: Oh and these oscillations may be due to having no bulk or bypass capacitors on LM386 supply pins.

Comment: @Justme: Pin5 capacitors were indeed placed in the wrong direction. I used two 100uF in parallel, because I could not find a 220uF.

Comment: @Justme: The capacitor on Pin7 (in series with 10R) is blocked by the electrolyte caps. It is an 100nF ceramic as shown in the added schematic

Comment: Adding an 100nF capacitor between Pin6-GND as bypass for the supply?

Comment: Where is **C?** on your breadboard? (Please use *proper* reference designators!) I mean the 100nF cap which is connected to pin 5 the IC. Did you perhaps accidently connect the 10 ohm directly to pin 5? Would explain the IC becoming hot

Comment: Not directly. Pin5-100nF-10R-GND (better visible in the edited schematic)

Comment: I am at a loss to explain your problems.  The LM386 is normally a stupidly simple chip to use.  I built amplifiers with them when I was a kid.  No Zobel network, no bypass capacitor on pin 7, no bypass on pin 6, and it just worked.  Are you sure that's an LM386 at all?  The markings on the chip itself are just a fuzzy blob in all your pictures.  Can you double check?

Comment: I thought so as well. Marking: MUAF LM386-M1

Comment: Reading on another forum https://www.diystompboxes.com/smfforum/index.php?topic=22914.0 it is stated that the high temperature might be ok. This would sill not explain the missing audio on the earphones or the bypass voltage <2.5V

Comment: What about the SMD to DIP adapter? Can't really see the connections. Is that a proper adapter and the SMD chip mounted in correct orientation?

Comment: I measured the adapter beforehand to see if Pin1 corresponds to Pad1. The 'marking' on the chip points to Pad1.  I also wasnt sure and just fliped the connections: Destroyed a chip yesterday

Comment: I try to buy a DIP version of this chip in the evening and some caps with the correct values (not just 'near' them). I try to built it more visible and better notations and will post a separate question if necessary

Comment: I hope you realize that ready-to-use modules exist based on the LM386, for example: https://www.amazon.com/LM386-Module-Amplifier-Adjustable-Resistance/dp/B07H38MQ81  On Ebay and Aliexpress you will find the cheapest ones.

Comment: just bought the DIP version and directly plugged it in the circuit above. Works out of the box. Vbias~2.45V, headphones and Arduino recognize sound. Seems to be either bad or damaged (possible by me) chips. The noise is almost unbearable, but there are a lot of articles out there to improve the noise (short wires, smaller caps <25V, maybe some filtering).